# ¿Es esta la mejor forma de crear un arreglo de opuestos?

Tags: javascript

Enunciado: Crea una función que tome como parámetro un arreglo de enteros y devuelva los negativos de estos y los negativos los devuelva como positivos.

```js
funcion = (array) => {
  let newArray = [];
  for (numero of array) {
    if (numero < 0) {
      numero = Math.abs(numero)
      newArray.push(numero)
    
    }
    else {
      numero = -Math.abs(numero)
      newArray.push(numero)
    }
  }
  return newArray;


};

document.write(funcion([-10, 20, 30, -40]));
```

Comment: ¿No es más fácil hacer `arreglo.push(-numero)` sin ningún if? O incluso mejor, `arreglo.map(n => -n)`.

Answer (score 7):

Nota: el comentario de mateo es más que correcto.

Para que complicar todo, si la contra de cualquier número (o sea, si es positivo, el negativo, y viceversa) no es más que matemáticamente el mismo número por -1, SIEMPRE...

Con lo cual, no hay que crear nuevos array, no hay que hacer un map, ni recorrer mil veces las cosas, ni usar un if, ni pasar una función...

```js
array = [-10,20,30,-40]
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 1 ) {  
    array[i] = array[i]*-1
}
document.write(array)
```

```js
array = [-10,20,30,-40]
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 1 ) {  
    array[i] = -array[i]
}
document.write(array)
```

Con esto sobra para devolver lo que buscabas.. si querías crear un nuevo array, podías crearlo ahí adentro, pero no se necesita ni un if para obtener el valor contrario.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede simplificar aún más el código, la mejor codificación dependerá de la interpretación de lo que se considere más clara y objetiva para resolver el problema.

Utilizando algunas técnicas de programación (modelos propuestos por desarrolladores para soluciones optimizadas) como la [*composición de funciones*](https://www.javatpoint.com/compositions-of-functions) y el [currying](https://www.javatpoint.com/currying-in-javascript), el código podrá ser claro y fácil de entender.

***Currying**

```js
   const negativos = (array) => array.map((n) => -n);
   document.write(negativos([-10, 20, 30, -40]));
```

La function `negativos` recibe un arreglo como argumento y utiliza el método `map()` para crear un nuevo arreglo basado en el arreglo que se le pasó. Al utilizar map(), lo que hace es mapear cada elemento del arreglo `n` y multiplicarlo por -1, lo que invierte el signo de todos los valores.

***Composición de funciones**

```js
const negativos = function (array) {
  return array.map((n) => (n < 0 ? -n : -n));
}
document.write(negativos([-10, 20, 30, -40]));
```

... al usar map() se crea un nuevo array y dentro del método map() hay una función anónima donde n representa cada elemento del array. Esta función verifica si el valor de `n` es menor que cero (`n < 0)`. En caso de que `n` sea menor que cero, se invertirá el signo del número.

Expresión de la operación ternaria

```
(n < 0 ? -n : n)
```

Devolverá el valor **absoluto** de `n`, en esta situación, si `n` es negativo, el absoluto será el opuesto, y si `n` es positivo, el valor absoluto será el propio número.

Lo que retorna es el valor absoluto de `n`, que puede ser positivo o negativo.

Comment: Esto solo transforma los negativos en positivos.. la pregunta dice "devuelva los negativos de estos y los negativos los devuelva como positivos."

Comment: Sí, me equivoqué, gracias por el comentario.@gbianchi

Comment: En la composicion de funciones, el if no tiene ningun sentido, siempre devuelve lo mismo...